# Proc corr output alpha values

Tags: sas, output, correlation, proc

I am trying to make a data set that has the p-values (or alpha values) along with the Pearson correlation coefficient for different variables.

I have about 6000 variables, and 4 variables I am correlating them with. I obtained the coefficients by using the output statement below

Full Code:

```
proc corr data=dat   outp = corr   noprint;
 var v1
     v2
     v3
     v4;
 with 
     v1
     v2
     v3
     v4
     v5
     ...;               *upto about v6000;
 run;
```

However, I would also like the alpha values that I usually get in the 'Results Viewer' window, as a data set.

Thank you.

Comment: Which proc are you using?  Please show your current code..

Comment: @RawFocus, I included the full code. I hope you can help me out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
*Get corrs;
proc corr data=test outp=Corr;
    var v1-v4;
    with v:;
run;

*Get Alphas;
ods output CronbachAlpha=Alpha;
proc corr data=test alpha nocorr;
    var v:;
run;
ods output close;

*Merge and Format;
data out(drop=Variables Alpha);
    set Alpha Corr;
    if Variables^='' then do;
        _TYPE_='Alpha';
        _NAME_=Variables;
         v1=alpha;
        v2=alpha;
        v3=alpha;
        v4=alpha;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I want 6000rows X 4cols table that has alpha values (and yes, cronbach alpha values are good.) The most critical issue here is the warning:<< WARNING: ALPHA option not allowed with WITH statement. >>   Also, I would like this in a data format not a result viewer window..

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the with statement. The ALPHA option won't work with that...but I don't think you need it. For the cronbach alphas, is it the cronbach for all of the variables v1-v6000? So then it would be the same across all 4 variables you will have columns for (v1-v4)?

Comment: Yes, it's true but most of the data I do not need. and I tried it now and It says 'the SAS System stopped processing this step because of insufficient memory.' (It was going to be 6004 buy 6004 matrix.)

Comment: @EricaJhLee - try the above.